# Converting UIDatePicker result to unix timestamp

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

My issue is trying to convert a Date Picker result into a unix timestamp. My client is adamant that it'd be saved as a unix timestamp into Firebase database. Im also quite new to the swift so...

```
let myTimeStamp = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: self.datePicker?.date)
```

this is the result of datePicker: 2016-12-03 00:56:00 +0000
This is the error: Cannot convert value of type 'Date?' to expected argument type 'TimeInterval' (aka 'Double')

Please help sirs & ma'ams!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You already have the `Date`. Since you want the timestamp, call:

```
let myTimeStamp = self.datePicker?.date.timeIntervalSince1970
```

`myTimeStamp` will be an `NSTimeInterval` with a value in Unix time.

Answer (score 1):

**Including swift 5+**
**Pass date like yourDatePicker.date **

```
 func getTimeStampFromDate(date: Date) -> String {
    return String(format: "%.0f", (date.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000))
}
```